# Selenium is not recognised by Anaconda

Tags: python, selenium, automation, anaconda, manjaro

I use `anaconda` for python, i  installed selenium via `pip/pip3` and chromedrivers.
But iam getting this error in my code

In `anaconda-navigator` selenium was showing as installed. I restarted my machine but error was same

I use `Manjaro KDE`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ujjawal/EXERCISE/py/automation.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `pip show selenium` in the terminal, which will indicate where selenium is installed.

Inside python, use `import sys; print(sys.path)` to check whether the location of selenium install directory is contained in it.

If not, fix the PATH.

Since this is a environment problem, I'm not able to give you detailed instruction on that.